# mysql foreign key creating table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS platforms ( " +
                   "id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                   "sites_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, " +
                   "baseline BLOB NULL, " +
                   "platform BLOB NULL, " +
                   "siteinfo BLOB NULL, " +
                   "databases BLOB NULL, " +
                   "PRIMARY KEY(id), " +
                   "INDEX (sites_id), " +
                   "FOREIGN KEY (sites_id) " +
                     "REFERENCES sites (id) " +
                        "ON DELETE NO ACTION " +
                        "ON UPDATE NO ACTION " +
                   ")ENGINE=InnoDB;";
```

this is the SQL query for a MySQL database I'm trying to create. However, I don't know why, I'm getting the following error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'databases BLOB NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id), INDEX (sites_id), FOREIGN KEY (sites_id) R' at line 1"

Could someone please point out for what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATABASES` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  Quote it by using the backtick `` ` `` character:

```
`databases` BLOB NULL
```